# Is this function injective? + Proof

Tags: proof-verification

I think this function is not injective, but I am unsure if I've correctly proven that.

Determine if the following statement is true or false and provide a proof to justify the answer.
\begin{align*}
g: \mathbb{R} & \to \mathbb{R} \\
g(x) &= \begin{cases}
      -x+1  & x>0\\
         -x^2 & x \leq 0
       \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Here's my attempt.
Proof: $g(-1)=-1=-1=g(2)$. $-1=-1$, but since $g(-1)=g(2)$, we can say that $g(-1)=g(2)\implies -1=2$ is false, and therefore for generic $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x_1)=g(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$ is false, so the function $g$ is not injective. $\blacksquare$

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your proof is correct, but you are overcomplicating the writing.  You are showing that $g$ is not injective by way of the counterexample $g(-1) = -1 = g(2)$.  That is really all you need to say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exposed two distinct points in the domain, $x=-1$ and $x=2$, with the same image under $g$. So $g$ is not injective. Done. A counterexample suffices.

Answer (score 0):

That seems comprehensive to me: to prove that your function is not injective in its domain, you only need to show one example of $f(x)=f(y)$ while $x\not = y$; $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a claim:

> **Claim**: $g$ is injective.

If the claim is true, then you need to provide a proof. Otherwise, you need to provide one *counter-example*, and you already did that. Therefore, the claim is false.